# GNOME/Ubuntu: Require additional confirmation on shutdown

Tags: linux, gnome, shutdown

My flatmates and I are sharing an Ubuntu (natty) based Media Centre PC that among other things runs MythTV to schedule and record TV.

I'm now looking for a convenient solution to prevent anybody from shutting down the system when one of us has scheduled a recording or has any other background job running that requires the PC to stay on.

It's not necessary to actually check if MythTV has anything scheduled, I'd much rather just be able to leave display a customisable message to anyone who tries to shut down the computer, with the option to ignore the warning ideally requiring some sort of input (click or better yet some keyboard input).

Comment: Shouldn't you just create a user without sudo privileges? Thus not allowing them to restart/shutdown the machine.

Comment: This sounds like a communication issue. I would just leave a note on the machine somewhere (preferably the monitor) telling people not to shut it off.